# Follow tcp stream - Where does field "Stream index" come from?

Tags: packet, wireshark, packet-capture

Wireshark has a that feature called *"follow tcp stream"*, under the menu item *"Analyze"*.

When I use it, a screen capture filter is generated, something like:

> tcp.stream eq 1

Where does this index come from?

I can't find any field in the packet that contains it...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

the stream index is an internal Wireshark mapping to: **[IP address A, TCP port A, IP address B,  TCP port B]**

All the packets for the same tcp.stream value should have the same values for these fields (though the src/dest will be switched for A->B and B->A packets)

see the Statistics/Conversations/TCP tab in Wireshark to show a summary of these streams

Answer (score 4):

Stream indexes are Wireshark-internal. It just uses a number to uniquely identify a TCP stream.

Answer (score 0):

Besides having same source and destination IPs and ports, packages within a stream conform **a whole open-transmit-close communication sequence**. So I guess Wireshark internally creates a new stream ID when SYN-ed package arrives and keeps track of all packages in this dialogue until both ends finish it (FIN/RST flags).

Filtering packages with tcp.stream filter is very useful to analyze a particular sequence.